# Duplicate XML elements and add attributes

Tags: xml, perl

I need a program that will duplicate XML elements and add attributes to them. It could be easier with an XSLT transform but I need the program to ask whether each matching element should be duplicated.

Here is a small and simple example of what I start with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<article>
  <section>
    <title>title</title>
    <para>text</para>
    <mediaobject>

      <imageobject>
        <imagedata fileref="filename.png" format="PNG"/>    
      </imageobject>

    </mediaobject>
    <para>text</para>
  </section>
</article>
```

What I want after passing the script

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<article>
  <section>
    <title>title</title>
    <para>text</para>
    <mediaobject>

      <imageobject arch="html;fo;fo-print">
        <imagedata fileref="filename.png" format="PNG"/>    
      </imageobject>

      <imageobject arch="screen">
        <imagedata fileref="filename.png" format="PNG" width="100%"/>    
      </imageobject>

    </mediaobject>
  </section>
</article>
```

I need the program to find
each `imageobject` element 
and ask whether it
should be duplicated.
If so then it is duplicated and attributes `arch` and `width` are added.

The XML file has to be external to the script and it would be nice if I could apply it to several files.

Comment: "Which parser can I use ?" — Questions asking for library recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: "how does it work ?" — It has documentation. There's no point in Stackoverflow just rewriting all the documentation that already exists. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/19068)

Comment: I was not asking for documentation but for ideas. But it seems confusing, so I removed this question. The other are more important.

Comment: @prodDBK: Removing that sentence has left your post without a question at all: you have simply described your situation. What are you asking, exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Tutorial: https://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/

```
use 5.024;
use IO::Prompt qw(prompt);
use XML::LibXML qw();

my $dom = XML::LibXML->new(line_numbers => 1)->parse_file('so51206867.xml');
for my $imageobject ($dom->findnodes('//imageobject')) {
    say 'Found at line ' . $imageobject->line_number;
    say $imageobject->toString;
    if (prompt 'Duplicate? ', '-yes') {
        my $copy = $imageobject->cloneNode(1);
        $imageobject->setAttribute(arch => 'html;fo;fo-print');
        $copy->setAttribute(arch => 'screen');
        $copy->findnodes('//imagedata')->get_node(1)->setAttribute(width => '100%');
        $imageobject->addSibling($copy);
    }
}
$dom->toFile('so51206867-out.xml');
```